# InfluxDB select different time between two row having same a field value

Tags: influxdb

I have a table like this on InfluxDB:

`+---------------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+
|     time      | sequence_number | action |        session_id        |
+---------------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+
| 1433322591220 |          270001 | delete | 556d85bfe26c3b3864617605 |
| 1433322553324 |          250001 | delete | 556d88e4e26c3b3b83c99d32 |
| 1433241828472 |          230001 | create | 556d88e4e26c3b3b83c99d32 |
| 1433241023633 |           80001 | create | 556d85bfe26c3b3864617605 |
| 1433239305306 |           70001 | create | 556d7f09e26c3b34e872b2ba |
+---------------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+`

Now I want to find the time range from a session be created to deleted, that means get `time` where `action=delete` minus `time` where `action=create` if they have same `session_id`

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done in InfluxQL, but you can ask in a way that makes it easier for the application. Something like: "SELECT time, session_id, action FROM your_measurement WHERE time >= 1433322591220 GROUP BY session_id, action". The GROUP BY clause will at least make the coding easier for the app which does the subtraction.